# Can't restart my httpd service

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, httpd

I just made a change to my PHP.ini file.  (my Linux dist is CentOS).  I figured I need to restart apache for that to take effect so I issued the command:

## service httpd restart

When doing that I get this error.

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 196 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load     
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_file_cache.so into server: 
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_file_cache.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not too well versed in Linux so I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: BTW, I've restarted my httpd service several times before.  So this is a new error.  I've install some packages with yum recently.  So maybe that messed up something.

Comment: I imagine I can comment out those offending lines of httpd.conf.  However, am I messing up something else by doing that?

Comment: More detail please. What is on line 196 of your httpd.conf and what change did you make to your php.ini file?

Comment: @Thread7 Please add some of your httpd for us to look at, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Check two things -
1. Syntax of httpd.conf using -t flag in httpd executable,
2. Is `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_file_cache.so` available ?

Comment: This is line 196: LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so      I don't think it has anything to do with the fact that I changed my PHP.INI.  But the change I made to that was I increased my upload_max_filesize value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment you posted it appears that Apache can't load the  mod_file_cache.so module that the conf is telling it to import. As far as I can recall certain editions of RHEL/CentOS don't have this included by default. Try commenting it with a # at the beginning of the line. Otherwise try rebuilding Apache with the module.

Comment: Yes, commenting it out worked.  I guess I'll live without it for now.